# How to have database name as variable in an SP?

Tags: sql-server, database

We use stored procedures exclusively here, and that raises a little problem. We cross reference two different databases like dbdev..table1 in dev, dbqa..table1 in qa, and dbprod..table1 in production.

So every time we deploy to a different environment, we have to search and replace from dbdev to dbqa or dbprod.

Is there a way to use synonym or whatever sql server mechanics to solve problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sqlcmd variables, which are supported by sqlcmd deployment of .sql provisioning scripts,a s well as by VSDB projects. So your provisioning script looks like:

```
create procedure usp_myProc
as
select .. from [$(crossdb)]..table1;
go
```

When deploying it in production you run `sqlcmd /E /I provisoning.sql /v crossdb=dbprod`, while the QA deployment will be done via `sqlcmd /E /I provisioning.sql /v crossdb=dbqa`. See [Using sqlcmd with Scripting Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx).

As a side note, I am working on a project that allows sqlcmd variables to be used from .Net SqlClient (SqlConnection, SqlCommand): the [dbutilsqlcmd](http://code.google.com/p/dbutilsqlcmd/) project.

Comment: SQLCMD variables must be specified before runtime, correct?  There's currently no support for running a SQLCMD script, and prompting the user for input before continuing?  I ask because Oracle's SQLPlus has supported the functionality for a while (9i for me)...

Comment: SQLCMD variables must be specified in startup command like as `/v` arguments, or they can be supplied as environment variables, or they can be set in the script with `:setvar`. There is no interactive way to supply a variable value.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 supports synonyms, so you can create synonym1 to refer to dbdev..table1 in dev environment, and to dbprod..table1 in prod environment. Your SP's (and probably views) just operate on the synonyms.

Update:

The *easiest* way to create synonyms:

```
exec sys.sp_MSforeachtable 
    'print ''CREATE SYNONYM '' + REPLACE(''?'', ''].['', ''].[syn_'') + 
    '' FOR [my_database].?
    GO'''
```

(there is a line break before GO)

Run and paste result into new query window.

Comment: Do you know if it there's an easy way to write a sql to dynamically make a synonym for each object?

Answer (score 1):

No.

It is not possible to create a Synonym for a database. That is a [popular request](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/311079/expand-synonym-to-other-entities-database-linked-server) though.

Is it really necessary to rename your databases for `dbdev`, `dbqa`, `dbprod` etc. though?

Comment: It's also been requested [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/288421/allow-create-synonym-for-database) by the same author. He must *really* want that feature. :-)

Comment: Right, the database names should be the same. It is the servers that should be different. You miss a lot of benefit if your dev and qa are in the same sql server as your production.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic sql

(forgive potential typos, but the concept is there)

```
Declare @dbname nvarchar(255), @sql nvarchar(max)
set @dbname = 'db1'

Set @sql = 'Select * From ' + @dbname + '.dbo.table1'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: It seems like find and replace is a much better option than this because it is messy and would carry over to production. Also, you run into problems if you try using this in user defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the database name as a parameter of your stored procedure, then use Dynamic SQL to construct your queries.

Ex:

```
CREATE PROC MyStoredProcedure @DBName VARCHAR(50) 
AS

   DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName + '.dbo.table1'
   EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Then you would simply call your stored procedure with the appropriate DB Name:

```
EXEC MyStoredProcedure 'dbdev'
```