# Dynamic database instance in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Okay. I have a database that has bunch of stored procedures and references another database like this:

```
select * from DatabaseName.dbo.tableName... or
Insert into DatabaseName.dbo.tableName....
```

So. It references it around 500-1000 times in stored procedures. Now, what happens is that I need to run these stored procedures from one database referencing another database, like this:

```
 select * from AnotherDatabaseName.dbo.tableName... or
 Insert into AnotherDatabaseName.dbo.tableName....
```

As far as I understand sql server 2008 r2 does not have anything new that could help it and I have to build dynamic queries every time with a parameter, right? If this is the case, is there any decent easy way to do it? 
I need to change every stored procedure and add a parameter @DatabaseInstance. Also, I need to reconfigure all of the queries. sounds scary. Any automated tool or something to help with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have database name as variable in an SP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578070/how-to-have-database-name-as-variable-in-an-sp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using code you can create synonym for the database in your DB. I.e. I'm using this code in SP to insert into specified database based on parameter (region)

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = N'TABLE_SYNONYM') DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[TABLE_SYNONYM]
IF @region_id not in (2,3) CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[TABLE_SYNONYM] FOR [DB_US].[dbo].[mytable]
IF @region_id = 2 CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[TABLE_SYNONYM] FOR [DB_EU].[dbo].[mytable]
IF @region_id = 3 CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[TABLE_SYNONYM] FOR [DB_Asia].[dbo].[mytable]

insert into [dbo].[TABLE_SYNONYM] (...) select ....
```

Comment: This look very interesting. I can do synonyms only for a specific table? I still do not understand why do we need insert into statement at the end.

Comment: you can create synonyms for:
Assembly (CLR) Stored Procedure, 
Assembly (CLR) Table-valued Function, 
Assembly (CLR) Scalar Function, 
Assembly Aggregate (CLR) Aggregate Functions, 
Replication-filter-procedure, 
Extended Stored Procedure, 
SQL Scalar Function, 
SQL Table-valued Function, 
SQL Inline-table-valued Function, 
SQL Stored Procedure, 
View, 
Table1 (User-defined), 

The insert statement is only an example. You can do everything with the synonym what is allowed for the underlying object.