# Script to create a schema using a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, schema

I'm surprised that this hasn't come up before but I haven't found anything in searches either here or elsewhere. I found something vaguely similar which indicates that the problem is that the Use command in my script lasts only for that one line, but there was no indication of how to work around that.

What I'm trying to do: Create a generic script to create a "template" database with all of my common schemas and tables. All of the variables (such as the database name) are intended to be set in the header so that they can be changed as needed and the script can be just run without needing to do any risky search and replace operations to change hard coded values.

What the problem is: I can't get the schemas to generate in the right database; they're all generating in Master. Trying to explicitly set the database didn't help; I just received runtime errors.

My skill level: Long time Access user but still in the foothills of exploring SQL Server. I'm sure (well, hoping) this this will be ridiculously easy for someone further up the slope.

Does anyone know how I can do something like this? (Existing code shown below.)

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(50) = 'TheDBName';

-- Assume that there's a bunch of code to drop and create the database goes here.
-- This code executes correctly.

SET @SQL = 'Use [' + @DBName + ']';

Print @SQL;

EXEC(@SQL);

SET @Counter = 1;

WHILE @Counter <=3

    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'CREATE SCHEMA [' +
        CASE @Counter
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Schema1'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Schema2'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Schema3'
        END

        SET @SQL = @SQL + '] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]';

        PRINT 'Creating Schemas, ' + @SQL;

        Exec(@SQL);

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;    
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `use` command only changes the current db in the scope you are in and dynamic SQL runs in a scope of its own.

Try this from `master`

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL  = N'use tempdb; print db_name()'
exec(@SQL)
print db_name()
```

Result:

```
tempdb
master
```

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(50) = 'TheDBName';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @SQLMain NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Counter int

SET @SQLMain = 'Use [' + @DBName + ']; exec(@SQL)';


SET @Counter = 1;

WHILE @Counter <=3
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = 'CREATE SCHEMA [' +
        CASE @Counter
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Schema1'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Schema2'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Schema3'
        END

  SET @SQL = @SQL + '] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]';

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQLMain, N'@SQL nvarchar(max)', @SQL;

  SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but I'm afraid that doesn't work for me. The line comes out as Use [MYDBTEMPLATE]; CREATE SCHEMA [SCHEMA1] AUTHORIZATION [dbo] This generated the error 'CREATE SCHEMA' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: But your revised code worked brilliantly! Thank you, thank you, you da man!

Comment: (I'd have voted it up as a useful answer, but alas I lack the reputation. I've flagged it as "the answer" though...)

Answer (score 0):

If you run USE statement inside EXEC() then run other statements also in EXEC()

**but**

you have to use `USE databasename` stmt. in every EXEC()

Comment: Thanks Oleg; I think that's what Mikael was indicating but then I hit the "must be the first statement" problem (which I forgot to mention in the initial post I've run across before.)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained your immediate problem but since this is really a deployment issue, as a general solution you might want to try [using SQLCMD variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578070/how-to-have-database-name-as-variable-in-an-sp) that you can then set at runtime from the command line. This would allow you to pass the database name and/or schema names into scripts dynamically so you can then automate your deployment using batch files or VS database projects.

Comment: Thanks for that; I've started taking a look through the relevant help files; that may well be useful in future.