# DDL Commands in Error Handled SQLCmd Scripts; Syntax Errors Which Don't Exist Without The Try/Catch Block

Tags: sql-server-2008, try-catch, ddl, sqlcmd

I'm still relatively new to SQL Server but love a lot of things about it, except for the array of "all-slightly-different-but-none-can-do-everything", "finicky-in-different-ways" scripting options where, just when you feel like you're starting to get a handle on things and are cruising, you slam into yet another roadblock. I've been down the dynamic SQL path (and have found the restrictions on variables having short lifetimes) and as per a previous suggestion that I received ( [Script to create a schema using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585577/script-to-create-a-schema-using-a-variable) ), am now trying to write sqlcmd scripts instead.

A lot of scripts work fine and dandy if you run them "naked". As soon as you put some of them into a Try / Catch block to implement error handling on them, however, you often run into ridiculous restrictions most notably DDL commands which "vant to be alone" and need to be the first/only statement in a batch. Go is useless in this context because if you put THAT anywhere inside a Try/Catch block it guarantees that you'll get a syntax error.

Obviously I've scoured the web on this (and have looked at some of the "similar questions" that appeared while editing this post) but keep coming up with examples which are either "naked" in the sense above, or are Try/Catch examples on code which doesn't have these restrictions.

In the case of creating a schema, I used the approach that had been suggested to me for dynamic SQL; I ran it through sp_executesql. That's not a problem since it's essentially one line of code, the problem is that I hit it again when I tried to create a trigger on a table (and am guessing that I will with some other Create commands).

```
CREATE TRIGGER MySchema.NoDelete 
    ON  MySchema.MyTable 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RAISERROR ('Deletions are not allowed on this table', 16,1)
END
```

Run this by itself and it's fine. Put Begin Try before it and End Try and a Catch block after it and you get:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.

with a red squiggly line on BEGIN with the bogus tool tip "Incorrect syntax near Begin, expecting External".

I tried the sp_executesql path with this again but:

- First, it also generated a bogus "Syntax error near $" error which is about as useful as telling me that there's some syntactical error, somewhere, between here and the planet Zargthorp" but more importantly:
- Second, even if I did get it to work for a relatively trivial trigger like this one, I'm having nightmares trying to imagine packaging a complex, multi-line trigger in such a fashion but even if I DID get past that;
- Third, it would make the code much more obscure and defeat one of the purposes of using scripts in the first place, that being self-documentation.

My questions therefore are:

- Is Try/Catch effectively useless for commands which, for reasons best known to MS designers,  need to live in isolated majesty like Create Trigger (and which aren't one-liners like Create Schema which can be neatly packaged up into sp_executesql); or
- In my relative newbieness have I missed some other way of working around the kind of restriction that I've slammed into with Create Trigger?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: I'm amazed that no-one has encountered this as an issue previously, but at least it did earn me a "Tumbleweed" badge. 8^> For what it's worth, the way I approached this was to separate out the trigger creation into a separate UPDATE TABLE script which does nothing else, and omit error handling on it. I error handle all that can be in my main scripts. It's not pretty but it gets the job done...